# Can I set min/max value of database sequence from Entity?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

Is there a way where I can the sequence max and min value from the entity itself

Comment: Why do you need it?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that it is possible to create a sequence with specific `MINVALUE` or `MAXVALUE` by using JPA or Hibernate.

The JPA specific annotation for this task is the [`SequenceGenerator`](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/persistence/SequenceGenerator.html) which does not accept the `MINVALUE` or the `MAXVALUE`. It optionally accepts the `initialValue` which affects the "STARTS WITH" value of the sequence and probably implicitly sets the `MINVALUE` or the `MAXVALUE`.

For example the [Oracle database](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_6015.htm#SQLRF54247) says regarding the `CREATE SEQUENCE` statement:

> **START WITH**
>
> Specify the first sequence number to be generated. Use
> this clause to start an ascending sequence at a value greater than its
> **minimum** or to start a descending sequence at a value less than its
> **maximum**. F**or ascending sequences, the default value is the minimum
> value of the sequence. For descending sequences, the default value is
> the maximum value of the sequence.** This integer value can have 28 or
> fewer digits.

There is the hibernate specific API [`GenericGenerator`](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.0/javadocs/org/hibernate/annotations/GenericGenerator.html) and [`SequenceStyleGenerator`](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.0/javadocs/org/hibernate/id/enhanced/SequenceStyleGenerator.html) which can be used to create a sequence (see an [example](https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-identifiers#3-sequence-generation)) but they too seem not to accept `MINVLAUE` or `MAXVALUE` as parameters.

Finally, a quick look into [Hibernate's code](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/5eedda9a467fef44d924f64203023b2345b8415f/hibernate-core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/dialect/Oracle8iDialect.java#L399) for Oracle DB suggests that indeed the `MINVALUE` AND `MAXVALUE` is set implicitly based on the provided `initialValue` as the Oracle documentation above suggests. For example here is the relevant code:

```
protected String getCreateSequenceString(String sequenceName, int initialValue, int incrementSize) {
        if ( initialValue < 0 && incrementSize > 0 ) {
            return
                String.format(
                        "%s minvalue %d start with %d increment by %d",
                        getCreateSequenceString( sequenceName ),
                        initialValue,
                        initialValue,
                        incrementSize
                );
        }
        else if ( initialValue > 0 && incrementSize < 0 ) {
            return
                String.format(
                        "%s maxvalue %d start with %d increment by %d",
                        getCreateSequenceString( sequenceName ),
                        initialValue,
                        initialValue,
                        incrementSize
                );
        }
        else {
            return
                String.format(
                        "%s start with %d increment by  %d",
                        getCreateSequenceString( sequenceName ),
                        initialValue,
                        incrementSize
                );
        }
    }
```

I assume that this should be the case for other databases except Oracle that support sequences too.